# Setter method doesnt work

Tags: java

my problem is the other two parametere doesnt work and just first parametere repeat in output?!

here is the main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Time object = new Time(8, 60, 13);
    System.out.println(object.getHour()+ ":" + object.getMinute() + ":" + object.getSecond());
}
```

and here is my Class:

```
public class Time {
private int hour;
private int minute;
private int second;

    public int getHour(){
    return hour;
}
public void setHour(int h){
    hour = h;
}
public int getMinute(){
    return hour;
}
public void setMinute(int m){
    minute = m;
}
public int getSecond(){
    return hour;
}
public void setSecond(int s){
    second = s;
}
public Time(int h,int m,int s){
    setHour(h);
    setMinute(m);
    setSecond(s);
}
```

Comment: What does the methods `getHour`, `getMinute` and `getSecond` return? And is that what you want?

Comment: Please check your own code in the future for such glaring errors as getters returning completely wrong values. You can't write `getHour() {return 0;}` and then go to stackoverflow saying `setHour(5)` did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setters are correct, but getters seems to be broken due to copy pasting.

You have a typo in your getters:

```
public int getMinute(){
    return hour; // You are returning hour instead of minute
}

public int getSecond(){
    return hour; // You are returning hour instead of second
}
```

You have to change it to:

```
public int getMinute(){
    return minute;
}

public int getSecond(){
    return second;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your getter getSecond() seems to return hour and not second.